# Making an item in an array visible using knockout

Tags: arrays, data-binding, knockout.js

I haven't been able to find a solution for this issue so far. I'm trying to populate a summary table when a quantity box has been changed in the main list. Here is my code as it sits currently:

```
<div class="mainItems">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: finalListItems">
                <li> <input class="qty" data-bind="value: qty, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" size="4"/><label data-bind="text: item" ></label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: finalListItems">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: item"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: qty"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

And the ViewBox:

```
function sortedListItem(qty, listItemName) {
var self = this;
self.qty = ko.observable(qty);
self.item = listItemName;
}   
var trialViewModel = function(){
var self = this;
self.availableListItems = [
    {itemName: "Here is Item 1"},
    {itemName: "Here is Item 2"},
    {itemName: "Here is Item 3"},
    {itemName: "Here is Item 4"},
    {itemName: "Here is Item 5"}        
];
self.finalListItems = ko.observableArray([
    new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[0].itemName),
    new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[1].itemName),
    new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[2].itemName),
    new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[3].itemName),
    new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[4].itemName)
]);
};
ko.applyBindings(trialViewModel());
```

I have also included a JSFiddle here so you can see the idea of what I am going for:

http://jsfiddle.net/RYmf7/

The issue is I only want the item visible in the summary if the qty box has been changed. I've haven't been able to tie a visibility binding to the individual item in the array and I haven't seen anything quite like this yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could flag each item as dirty when the value is changed. The summary list will be built based on which items have new quantities.

http://jsfiddle.net/RYmf7/2/

```
function sortedListItem(qty, listItemName) {
    var self = this;
    self.originalqty = qty;
    self.qty = ko.observable(qty);
    self.item = listItemName;

    self.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.originalqty != self.qty();
    }, this);
}

var trialViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.availableListItems = [
        {itemName: "Here is Item 1"},
        {itemName: "Here is Item 2"},
        {itemName: "Here is Item 3"},
        {itemName: "Here is Item 4"},
        {itemName: "Here is Item 5"}        
    ];

    self.finalListItems = ko.observableArray([
        new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[0].itemName),
        new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[1].itemName),
        new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[2].itemName),
        new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[3].itemName),
        new sortedListItem(ko.observable.qty, self.availableListItems[4].itemName)
    ]);

    self.summaryListItems = ko.computed(function() {
        var summaryItems = [];

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.finalListItems(), function(item) {
            if (item.isDirty()) {
                summaryItems.push(item);
            }
        });
        return summaryItems;
    });

};

ko.applyBindings(trialViewModel());
```

Comment: I was actually unaware of the foreach utility. I had been attempting a similar solution based on the idea Joseph gave above using a for loop and then using some virtual DOM elements. 
I did make a couple of minor tweaks: instead of adding a new variable (originalqty), I changed the quantity parameter of finalListItems to be ' '. Then, I was able to call a function "isChanged" when self.qty != ' '. Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to do this, but here's an updated fiddle that might get you started down a path:  http://jsfiddle.net/RYmf7/1/

The idea is to add an `isVisible` property to the model for each individual item, and use that for a visible data binding.

```
//model for the sortedListItem
function sortedListItem(qty, listItemName) {
    var self = this;
    self.qty = ko.observable(qty);
    self.item = listItemName;
    self.isVisible = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.qty() !== 0;
    });
}
```